# How to remove win 8 and resell disc

Tags: windows, windows-8

I don't like windows 8 without the touchscreen, so what would I need to do to be able to resell the windows 8 disc.
cheers alex

Comment: If Windows 8 came preinstalled on the machine then in order to sell your copy of Windows 8 you will need to sell your machine. Preinstalled copies have no rights to be transferred to other computers.

Answer (score 0):

This depends upon License type of your  windows 8 .The EULA states whether licenses are transferable to a third party .

- You can never transfer an OEM license to a different computer although you can sell the machine itself.
- If License type of your  windows 8 is transferable , While transferring a license, you may only have it installed on one computer at a time.**Just uninstall the license** before transfering it to the third party.

Answer (score -2):

You can't resell a Windows Operating System. It is against the laws. As Mokubai said, You have to sell you machine inorder to make it legal.